# WebView height = wrap_content with changing font size doesn't work

Tags: android, layout, webview

I have webview with layout_height = "wrap_content". If I increase default font size, then webview height increases too. But if I decrease default font size, then webview height doesn't decrease. So there is empty space on the bottom remaining.

I've tried following trick:

```
articleContent.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(fontSize);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, subtitleTextView.getId());
articleContent.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

But it didn't help. I know there is the way to fix it by recreating WebView with a code when I changing default font size, but in my situation I can not do like that. I need to keep webview, because there are some views bellow it, and I can not recreate them too.

Comment: Having the same issue with a WebView in a ScrollView when loading it with contents of different lengths. Maybe it's not smart to use it in a ScrollView though...

Comment: Similar issue here on android 4.4. After loading shorter contents using loadDataWithBaseURL, the webview in a linearlayout wrapped by a scrollview won't scale down. However, 1.when using `setTextZoom(smaller)`, the webview does shrink down accordingly. 2.I don't see this problem on higher versions.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what exactly of this should help? wraping webview into linear layout or setting witdh wrap content and height fill parent?

Comment: I can't accept that answer. The question asks how to set it to "wrap_content" and you suggest a fixed height instead (fill_parent). Of course then the webview has a constant height...

Answer (score 4):

The only solution I have found that actually works, is in the com.android.email client that comes with the Android Open Source Project.  There, they have a RigidWebView which works with the wrap_content and will resize accordingly when the content changes.   Source code for this can be found here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Email/+/c19c1226da4a32e49e81c202478384f0348bcfef/src/com/android/email/view/RigidWebView.java

You'll need the Clock and Throttle classes that come with it, but with minor changes to the code, you can make it so it works in your app.  Then anywhere where you would normally define a WebView, you can use RigidWebView instead.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is referenced Android's issue tracker here: 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18726

If what you really want is a WebView wrapping your content it looks like the only work-around at the moment is to create a new WebView every time your content changes (which may not be acceptable when targeting low memory devices). It is the solution I have adopted anyway.

Comment: Google marked it fixed since KitKat 4.4, but I haven't tested yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
webview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue should be fixed in the KitKat WebView.

For WebView versions before KitKat there aren't any good workarounds I know of. Altering the width of the WebView should force a height recalculation but it might also lead to visual glitches.

I think that temporarily forcing a height of 0 and then flipping it back to wrap_contents should get rid of the excess padding too.

Comment: I am having the same issue, My web view app is supposed to have different font size, when I increase the font size and then go back the smaller font size, the web view causes so much empty space. Is there a way to fix it???

Answer (score 1):

Just add this

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams wv_l =  new 

    LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                                wv.setLayoutParams(wv_l);
```

Comment: It does not work for me. White space was still there.

Comment: check your inside html with css borders red line to check if anything has to do with the page itself..

Answer (score -3):

Try the following combination:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="200dp"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
         style="@style/Etiquetas"
         android:text="@string/hola" />

     <WebView android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
         android:id="@+id/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@null" >
     </WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
LinearLayout. LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.setLayoutParams(params);
WebView  zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz); 
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.loadData(Html.fromHtml(mistringsqlite).toString(), "text/html", null);
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low-quality because of its length and content - adding a bit of explanation might help.