# WebView doesn't resize

Tags: android, webview, resize, android-webview

I've developed a web application for Firefox OS, but I wanted to make it run "natively" in Android. My application consists of a dialogue box that is a `div` which fills the entire page when visible, which I've tested using the Firefox responsive design tool and it does resize correctly. When a soft keyboard appears, I would want the dialogue to resize to the viewport left over as there are some buttons at the bottom of the dialogue.

I created an application with a single activity that contains just a `WebView`. I wanted to the view to resize when the keyboard appears, so I used:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustResize"
```

which didn't seem to make any difference to the `WebView` when the keyboard was visible. I looked online and there were many people complaining about this problem, but they all had the same thing in common, they were using the `Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` theme, which I am not. I tried all of the solutions to that problem, but none of them worked.

I then began to wonder if there was a bug in `WebView` which meant it didn't resize. So, I wrote a custom `View` which printed the dimensions in `onLayout`.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    Log.d(TAG, t + " " + r + " " + b + " " + l);
}
```

And sure enough, the view was being resized correctly when the keyboard appeared and disappared. So, I did some more research and I found a few answers that said that you need to hide the `WebView`, reload it, and then show it again.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    Log.d(TAG, t + " " + r + " " + b + " " + l);

    mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mWebView.layout(l, t, r, b);
    mWebView.invalidate();
    mWebView.reload();
    mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Again, this did not solve my problem. (And as a side point, this is a web-app with a single .html file and JS causes the state of all the elements in the app to change in runtime, so reloading it is not an option.)

My question is whether anyone knows of a way of resizing a `WebView` once the content has been loaded when the keyboard is visible.

Comment: I've never had this issue before. My webview and it's content, always resizes properly. What device are you testing with? Also, I use "stateHidden|adjustResize"

Comment: Wow... you're right! I created an empty html page with a `fixed` positioned div and that resized as expected. The problem was that I have to use `position: absolute;` due to a bug in WebKit which causes `fixed` elements to not react to any `-webkit-transform`, so I'll have to find another way.

Comment: Glad to help. In general I found using WebView too buggy (especially between devices) and will avoid using them at all costs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I was using `position: absolute` inside a `position: fixed` `div`. The outer `div` was resizing properly, but the inner one was not. The reason I had to use `position: absolute` was because there is a bug in WebKit which means that you cannot `transform` `fixed` positioned divs.

Answer (score 4):

That's not exactly the answer to your question, but you will also notice that WebView does re-size when it's about getting bigger, but doesn't reduce when the content's height decreases, as I have already answered on this question: [WebView height = wrap_content with changing font size doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765059/webview-height-wrap-content-with-changing-font-size-doesnt-work)

The bug/feature is referenced on Google's issue tracker:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18726

Please don't blame me, I just wanted to point that for further problems you could encounter with WebView.