# Java/Android: Dynamically Resizing WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a textual `WebView` that I'm trying to re-size the contents of each time the user puts next text in. The idea is to fit the `WebView` into the screen without it getting cut off and without showing the scroll bars.

Currently the only reliable method that I have is extending the `WebView` class and using the base class's `protected` methods that  measure the scrolling bar distances:

```
public class ExtendedWebView extends WebView {
    public ExtendedWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public ExtendedWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public int getHorRange() {
        return computeHorizontalScrollRange();
    }
    public int getVerRange() {
        return computeVerticalScrollRange();
    }
    public int getScreenX() {
        return computeHorizontalScrollExtent();
    }
    public int getScreenY() {
        return computeVerticalScrollExtent();
    }
}
```

The only limitation I found is if the content is smaller and doesn't get out of bounds, there's no way to know how small it is, as it will return the size of the `WebView`.

Under another thread, I have the constantly looping method that checks if the `WebView` is out of bounds, and then re-sizes it. Here's the associated code, simplified:

```
ExtendedWebView webView;   //   assume this is initialized
while (true) {

    int a, b, c, d;
    a = webView.getHorRange();
    b = webView.getScreenX();
    c = webView.getVerRange();
    d = webView.getScreenY();

    if (a > b || c > d) {
        //shrinking to accommodate text...
        int val, x, y;
        x = a - b;
        y = c - d;
        val = x > y ? x : y;
        val*=0.1;
        val = val == 0 ? 1 : val;
        scale-=val;
    }
    else{
        //TODO enlarging webView
    }
    if (scale <= 50) {
        scale = 50;
        //prevent from webView being too small
    }

    if (scale > 200)
        scale = 200;
    webView.setInitialScale(scale);
}
```

The shrinking of the `WebView` works, what I can't figure out is how to enlarge it again once the text has been erased. Whenever I tried simply increasing the scale from the `else` block, it simply alternates between enlarging and shrinking the text, and the limitation of not knowing the size of the content while it has no scroll bars hinders me from making better solutions.

To clarify, it's not the `WebView` that I'm trying to re-size, but it's contents.

Comment: Can you show your layout? Have you tried wrap_content?

Comment: I don't understand what does `wrap_content` has to do with the size of my text.

Comment: Also have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765059/webview-height-wrap-content-with-changing-font-size-doesnt-work

Comment: Maybe I haven't understand you, but I thought you just want to have the WebView the exact (minimal) size of the content. I am not sure it works in your case, but usually wrap_content is what I would try 1st for any other layout element

Comment: It's not my problem. My `WebView` doesn't change its size, it's wrapped. The contents of the `WebView` do. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Why don't you use `webView.getContentHeight()` in case there's no scroller?

Comment: In javascript, you could measure the actual size of the textual content and either pass that back for the adjustment or do the adjustment entirely in JS.  Ugly though.

Comment: @Gavriel Because there's no `webView.getContentWidth()` method to go with that.  So even if I did, that's only half of the problem...

Comment: It's here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getContentHeight() since API1, and you wrote you have the other half working, haven't you?

Comment: Yeah, the height is there, but not the WIDTH. The text will still get out of bounds horizontally. If there was a method to get the width my problems would be solved.