# Re-sizing a box with an unknown parameter

Tags: java

Multiple times I have tried and failed to get a solution for my questions, probably because the question is riddled with distractions and irrelevancies. Here, I made my best attempt to simplify the problem I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107089/java-android-dynamically-resizing-webview).

This is the most rudimentary simplification I could make. I tried to make the syntax vague and therefore did not add any tags. If I'm wrong in doing this, please correct me.

```
/// REMEMBER!!!!!!!!!!!!!: this code is an analogy and a simplification of a problem

static int staticSize = 200;

class Box {
    private int size = 200;

    void randomlyChangeBoxSize(){ size += random(-20,20); }
    int getBoxSize(){ return size >= staticSize ? size : staticSize; }
}

Box box;

static void main(){
    while(true){
        int boxSize = box.getBoxSize();
        if(bosSize>staticSize)
            staticSize= boxSize;
        else
            ???????????     // is it possible to shrink?

        changingBox.size+= random(-10,10);
    }
}
```

My problem is pretty self-explanatory. I need to re-size the `staticSize` vaue according to the `box.size` field.

The code only works one way, making `staticSize` bigger as `box.size` grows, but let's assume `box.size` shrinks. What then? How can we re-size down? Is it even possible in the current premise?

What I did try is shrinking `staticSize` until it was smaller than `box.size`, but the side-effect is that `staticSize` would temporarily be smaller, and I don't want that.

Comment: The possibility of the shrink is based on what you expect the outcome be. What are you using Box for?

Comment: The box is unexpected re-sizing content. The `staticSize` is a screen. The screen needs to re-size according to the box.

Comment: your logic seems to be hidden; if you want staticSize to be boxSize simply say staticSize=boxSize; no matter what - beyond that you have to explain how you want that shrinking to happen: gradually -- by chunks -=10 what??

Comment: `box.size` is private so you can only use the given method. Remember that this is no functional code, but an analogy for a real problem.